# run shell command over named pipes from php

Tags: php, linux, named-pipes

I have an application in php that works on the docker. I would like to send a command from php through named pipes. If i go to container from console and run this command then that works, but from php code nothing happens.

Command example:

```
system('echo "mkdir -p /some_new_dir" > hostpipe/mypipe');
// or another test
system('cat /application/file_with_command > /application/hostpipe/mypipe');
```

I tried to use exec/shell_exec/system or Symfony process but it didn't help.
came across information to take advantage of `fopen` but i'm not sure how i could use it.
I'm traying like this, but no success:

```php
$out = fopen(base_path("hostpipe/mypipe"),"w");
fwrite($out,"mkdir -p /some_new_dir");
fclose($out);
```

permissions looks ok because i make chmod and for e.g. that works:

```
system('mkdir -p ' . base_path("/some_new_dir"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a permissions issue where the PHP process owner does not have permission to create the named pipe.  I would use `system` or `exec` instead of `shell_exec` so that you can inspect the command's output.

Comment: with fopen I was getting messages about permissions, but I used chmod, the problem resolved, so it seems to me that there is no problem here